# I have a question about the error "The user is blocked from live streaming"

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

My app users whose account has less than 1,000 subscribers are blocked from live-streaming.

liveBroadcasts.insert API request (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/errors#liveBroadcasts_youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert)

- POST
  [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id%2Csnippet%2Cstatus&fields=id&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id%2Csnippet%2Cstatus&fields=id&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)
- error message:
  The user is blocked from live streaming. (
  extendedHelp: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853834 )

However,

we created another project at https://console.developers.google.com and made new Credentials, OAuth 2.0 client ID for Android.

and we tested it with sames package name and the error does not appear.

Also, Google play there are many other apps with similar live streaming features and they let streaming with less than 1,000 subscribers subscribers without any problems.

I wonder if there is any specific policy about Restrictions on live streaming and project-id.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I have the same issue.